# Difference between Condensin and Cohesin proteins?

Tags: proteins, chromosome

The chromosomal DNA is stacked with help of cohesin and condensin protein in which particular manner? Can cohesin be said to form kinetochore? How would they vary exactly?
The terms are so narrowly windowed that they squeeze my brain through...!!! thank you for your kind help ^_^

Comment: Hi and welcome to bio.SE! When asking your questions, try to be as clear and provide as much information as is possible/relevant to help you get the best answer. Here, I think you need to separate your questions out a bit - you're asking about the difference in functions of the 2 proteins (cohesin and condesin), and you're also asking about cohesin's role in forming the kinetochore (related, but slightly separate). And what are you referring to when you ask 'how do they vary'? The 2 proteins? Don't be afraid to write a couple of paragraphs so that it is clear what you're asking. Thanks.

Comment: Hello sir...thank you so much for you guidance. When i said how do they vary am asking for the difference in their functioning sir as you rightly guessed. Once again thank you for your feedback and guidance.

Comment: You can edit your original question (by clicking 'edit', next to the vote buttons) to make it clearer, and tidy it up. I can do this if you would rather. Also my name is Luke, feel free to use it! :)

Answer (score 2):

### Condensin

**Condensin I:** present in *cytoplasm* during interphase, has access to chromosomes after prophase. Contributes to condensed chromosome assembly during prometaphase and metaphase [1].

**Condensin II:** present in *nucleus* during interphase, involved in chromosome condensation. Contributes to condensed chromosome assembly during prometaphase and metaphase [1].

### Cohesin

It keeps sister chromatids connected with each other during metaphase and ensures that each sister chromatid segregates to opposite poles. "It facilitates spindle attachment onto chromosomes. It facilitates DNA repair by recombination." [2]

---

References:

1. Wikipedia contributors, "Condensin," Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia, http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Condensin&oldid=606814199 (accessed July 29, 2014).
2. Wikipedia contributors, "Cohesin," Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia, http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Cohesin&oldid=617481362 (accessed July 29, 2014).